# NullInjectorError: No provider for ActiveCartService

Tags: spartacus-storefront

After I moved to 6.4 I have a component that uses ActiveCartService to add products but it no longer works (worked in V4) and in the console I get:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ActiveCartService!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
```

I add the ActiveCartService to a component using the constructor and import as follows:

```
import { ActiveCartService } from '@spartacus/cart/base/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'sample-cart',
  templateUrl: './sample-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-cart.component.scss']
})
export class SampleCartComponent {


  public constructor(private cart:ActiveCartService){
    
  }
```

The service is never instantiated.

Comment: Did you try using `ActiveCartFacade` instead of `ActiveCartService`? More explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307446/error-no-provider-for-activecartservice-when-extending-checkoutstepssetguard