# Error: No provider for ActiveCartService! - when extending CheckoutStepsSetGuard in Spartacus

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

> I am having the following errors when I try to override and extend the `CheckoutStepsSetGuard` :
>
> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid CanActivate guard in cmsMapping
> Error: Invalid CanActivate guard in cmsMapping
> (...)
> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CheckoutStepsSetGuard -> > MyCheckoutStepsSetGuard -> ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService]: 
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ActiveCartService!
> ```
>
> Do you know what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

What this Angular Dependency Injection error might mean in the context of SAP Spartacus:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CheckoutStepsSetGuard -> MyCheckoutStepsSetGuard -> ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService -> ActiveCartService]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for ActiveCartService!
```

It looks that the `ActiveCartService` hasn't been provided yet, while it's already was attempted to be injected.
I guess there is a race condition - we try to inject the service but the JS chunk with the cart functionality hasn't been lazy loaded yet (and the implementation of `ActiveCartService` wasn't provided yet).

I believe the remedy to such an issue is using the proxy `ActiveCartFacade` instead (`Facade` instead of `Service`). The `Facade` is a safe proxy object for accessing the `ActiveCartService` even when it's implementation not lazy loaded yet. Actually, calling any method of the `ActiveCartFacade` will implicitly trigger for you the lazy loading of the whole JS chunk with the cart functionality in the background, including the loading and providing of the the actual implementation of the `ActiveCartService`.

For more, see the [official SAP Spartacus docs for Proxy Facades](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/f44487ba0e984e129039a40d41bf81b8.html?q=lazy%20loading).